# Using javascript in ASP.NET Composite control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, composite-controls, asp.net-customcontrol

I have a custom asp.net server control to display images.What I need now is to draw a rectangle on the center of image and the rectangle should be re sizable by dragging on its edges.Is it possible to accomplish this using JavaScript ?. I need to embed that script in that control. Is it possible ?

Comment: Do any of these do what you want? http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=59 GIYF

Comment: Can I do it inside the control.I cannot use  a separate JavaScript file. I have to do it everything inside the control itself. I am using asp.net 2.0 without ajax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include a javascript file in a server control.

Add a reference to the assemblyinfo.cs

```
[assembly: WebResource("Custom.js", "text/javascript")]
```

Then a reference on the PreRender:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    string resourceName = "Custom.js";

    ClientScriptManager cs = this.Page.ClientScript;
    cs.RegisterClientScriptResource(typeof(CustomControls.Custom), resourceName);
}
```

[Here is a nice article on the subject](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/04/29/creating-custom-asp-net-server-controls-with-embedded-javascript.aspx)

Comment: I've already tried this. But it is not working in my case :-( . Actually my control has a label,text box and Image Control.What I need is to draw a re-sizable rectangle on the image

Comment: You could try using jquery to help with the resizable rectangle.  check out [resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#default)

Comment: How do I access controls from the script.When I tried accessing using getElementById("controlname") it returns null